# Ruby On Rails - Retrieve data from text box a display its contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I have a simple application which connects to twitter. The application has a search text box on the home page and a submit button.Also there is a model and the controller for the same. I want to search some keywords dynamically on twitter and then display them on the home page of our application. I have created a text box and submit button in the "index.html.erb" page. I don't know how to take the keyword and pass into the controller. Then i want to display the result of the search. Can anyone site an example for the same ? Kindly suggest errors /changes in the code. like-this ruby on rails

**The contents of the index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Tweets about New Year Resolution</h1>

<tr><td>Enter keyword  <input type = "text" name = "keyword"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type = "submit" value = "SEARCH"></td></tr>


<%= form_tag(tweets/index, :method => "get") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Enter keyword :") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
    <%= submit_tag("SEARCH") %>
<% end %>

<div id="container">
<ul>
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
    <li class="<%=cycle('odd', '')%>">
        <%= link_to tweet.from_user, "http://twitter.com/#{tweet.from_user}", :class => "username", :target => "_blank" %>  
        <div class="tweet_text_area">
            <div class="tweet_text">
                <%=raw display_content_with_links(tweet.text) %>
            </div>
            <div class="tweet_created_at">
                <%= time_ago_in_words tweet.twitter_created_at %> ago
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
```

**The contents of the controller tweets.rb**

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #Get the tweets (records) from the model Ordered by 'twitter_created_at' descending

   searchValue = params[:keyword] 

 if Tweet.count > 0                         
               Tweet.delete_all        
    end    
     Tweet.get_latest_new_year_resolution_tweets("iphone")

    @tweets = Tweet.order("twitter_created_at desc")   


  end

end
```

Comment: I think you should change `searchValue = params[:keyword]` to `searchValue = params[ :q ]` to grab the input and remove `td/tr` part

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice [railscast about search forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form) which you can learn from.

You may also learn from [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model), [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes) and [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes) if you want to avoid DB access.

Answer (score 0):

One things I noticed is that your input field is named `q` in HTML where else your controller action awaits `params[:keyword]`. Try changing the input field:

```
<%= text_field_tag(:keyword) %>
```

The url in the form tag helper should be quoted as well:

```
form_tag("tweets/index", :method => "get")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do i need to make some changes there also ?

Comment: If you are referring to the form_tag helper: yes. I would expect the view raising an exception otherwise.

Comment: I want to remove the scriplets in the code
<%= form_tag(tweets/index, :method => "get") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "Enter keyword :") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
    <%= submit_tag("SEARCH") %>
<% end %>
and use normal html. Also want to add a conditon in the index.html.erb , that the data should be displayed only if the object is NOT Null. Kindly help with the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>

     .......

   <%end%>
```

will be executed/outputted only when @tweets has at least one element. If you really want to make a check , then use

```
   <%if @tweets.empty? %>
```

wherever you want. Please not that @tweet.nil? may return false even if the array is empty.

You are going to get Exception when you submit the search form to TweetsController. By default, when you submit a form via POST to a controller, its 'create' action/method or 'update' action is called not the 'index' action as you expect.

You may need to an define additional action for that TweetsController; Something like 'search'; Then you may either use 
       form_tag(:action=>"search" , :controller=>"Twitter", :method => "get") 
or something like that. You should additionally specify that you have a 'search' resource accessed via GET/POST) , in routes.rb file .

in your TweetsController

```
    def search

       @tweets=  Tweet.where("text LIKE %#{params[:q]}%")
       render :action=>"index" #show the home page itself
    end
```